# How do I plot a time series using a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to plot a time series using a dataframe like what is below. But it's giving me some errors. What's is the best approach to do that?

```
Time    Goods
T1-1985 4009
T2-1985 4321
T3-1985 4224
T4-1985 3944
T1-1986 4123
T2-1986 4522
T3-1986 4657
T4-1986 4030
T1-1987 4493
T2-1987 4806
T3-1987 4551
T4-1987 4485
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ApplianceShipments.csv')

time = df['Time']
goods = df['Goods']

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('goods (in 000s)')
df.plot(time,goods)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
df = pd.read_csv('ApplianceShipments.csv')

plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('goods (in 000s)')
df.plot("Time", "Goods")
```

Comment: yeah, I think the problem was with my Jupiter notebook. It works now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For your case, assuming your csv is read and your df.columns returns `Index(['Time', 'Goods'], dtype='object')`

Just executing `df.plot("Time", "Goods")`  should do the job